# Omitting schedule in module's crontab config xml

Tags: module, configuration, cron, ee-1.13

I see this in the `Mage_Log` `config.xml`

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <log_clean>
            <run>
                <model>log/cron::logClean</model>
            </run>
        </log_clean>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

and noticed that the `<schedule>` tag is omitted. I know this cron job is schedule to run at what is set in the System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log Cleaning configuration, but I don't see how this connection is made. How does Magento know when to run this cron based on the configuration in admin panel? I'm trying to do something similar for a custom module.

I'm using Magento EE 1.13.0.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The schedule tag would be omitted here because this cron task is disabled by default. In the admin (System -> Configuration -> System -> Log Cleaning) you'll find the flag to turn it on as well as an option to choose the run/schedule frequency.

When the task is disabled, the schedule config value is stored as `NULL` so that it never turns up in the `cron_schedule` table when it's not supposed to run.

As soon as you turn it on, you'll find a value in the `core_config_data` table for `crontab/jobs/log_clean/schedule/cron_expr` defining the frequency. This value will be honored just like the one in the xml file would normally be were it present.

Since you're wanting to do something similar here, I would suggest taking a look at the system.xml file from the Mage_Log module to see what scaffolding they have in place to setup the configuration options to store the schedule config value.

Comment: Ah, the `<backend_model>` in system.xml is what manages that. I was wondering what that did. Thanks!

Comment: i think this ansewer is missing the how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `Mage/Log/etc/config.xml` file you can see it has invoked the `logClean()` function located in `Mage_Log_Model_Cron` class. Have a look at that function.

```
   /**
     * Clean logs
     *
     * @return Mage_Log_Model_Cron
     */
    public function logClean()
    {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_LOG_CLEAN_ENABLED)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->_errors = array();

        try {
            Mage::getModel('log/log')->clean();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_errors[] = $e->getMessage();
            $this->_errors[] = $e->getTrace();
        }

        $this->_sendLogCleanEmail();

        return $this;
    }
```

The following line in this function gets the configuration value for enabling the log.

```
Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_LOG_CLEAN_ENABLED)
```

Here this `XML_PATH_LOG_CLEAN_ENABLED = 'system/log/enabled'` . So Magento knows whether the logging is enabled or not in the system configuration.
 Then it'll continue with the functions as per they have been invoked.

Comment: My question was how does Magento's Cron know when to schedule and run this cron job logClean()? You can set what time to run it at in System > Configuration, but I don't see where it grabs that data in code.

Answer (score 0):

to add more precision here is where exactly the how log cron schedule is generated:

in th file:
app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Log.php
which has the function :

```
/**
 * Clean logs
 *
 * @param Mage_Log_Model_Log $object
 * @return Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Log
 */
public function clean(Mage_Log_Model_Log $object)
{
    $cleanTime = $object->getLogCleanTime(); // this is the line you want

    Mage::dispatchEvent('log_log_clean_before', array(
        'log'   => $object
    ));

    $this->_cleanVisitors($cleanTime);
    $this->_cleanCustomers($cleanTime);
    $this->_cleanUrls();

    Mage::dispatchEvent('log_log_clean_after', array(
        'log'   => $object
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

As you see above in the function Mage_Log_Model_Log::getLogCleanTime() all the magic happens :p

```
public function getLogCleanTime()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_LOG_CLEAN_DAYS) * 60 * 60 * 24; 
    //here is the formula :D
}
```

so it is now clear that the schedule is computed based on the configuration key :

```
const XML_LOG_CLEAN_DAYS = 'system/log/clean_after_day'
```